# How do I find the iOS Product Bundle Identifier without XCode?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, auth0

I'm on a linux machine and am unable to run XCode. I have a React Native application. Based on what I've read online, the only way to view the Product Bundle Identifier is to run XCode which isn't possible for me. I need this for my app's Auth0 integration. I use expo to run the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. What you need to do is go to the ios folder (If you don't see it, you have to run expo eject), then go into the chatapp.xcodeproj directory, and open the project.pbxproj as a plaintext file. After that, look for "PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER" and you should find what you're looking for!